# How to show in your thesis that a related work was published after your publication and did a similar things?

Tags: publications, citations, plagiarism

I am currently writing my dissertation and at the beginning, I published a conference paper that proposes how something can be used for a special purpose. I have cited someones something who never used this before for this purpose. Two years later, this person publishes a paper like I had and proposing the same thing I have proposed before, but did not cite me.

Now I am writing related work and I would like to mention that I published this idea earlier. Otherwise one can think I have reproduced this work, but they reproduced mine. How do I write this correctly that in the meantime this paper was published after my original publication?

Comment: What do you mean by "...that I had proposed before"? Do you mean an uncited published result or just an idea? It isn't clear from what you write that it is plagiarism, actually. "proposes how something can be used..." is pretty nebulous.

Comment: I made a comprehensive literature survey which is very very similar and stated the same findings and then making the same thing as I have done. I proposed the idea and then I conducted data and showed on an example case that it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can just share it. Perhaps mention it as a result "in parallel" or "independently".

You don't need to point out that you did it first or that they didn't cite you (this looks petty), just point out it exists and it's similar. Cite yourself, too, of course.

Readers can follow the two citation paths and see that yours was indeed first, and also that the other was independent. These things happen all the time, and lots of theorems are named after multiple publications of the same thing (sometimes including those "rediscovered" decades later, especially when a result crosses field boundaries and those from before the digital age).

Comment: Ok, I also found it would sound petty, but I would like to know how it is normally done.